# rewrite and redirect url problem in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'd like to redirect

> /any_path_to/oldfile.html

TO

> /newfile.html

for my website. First `/` is for showing root directory.

I found below statement for using in .htaccess file but i am not sure if it is correct.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^oldfile.html$ /newfile.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: just remove `^` and it should be OK. Also, use `R=302` while you are testing, when you have everything working correctly then change to `R=301`

Comment: @DusanBajic, Thanks, i'll try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version with a few corrections:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /oldfile\.html$ /newfile.html [R=301]
```

The pattern is more precise than the one suggested by @DusanBajic in the comments.

The `L` flag is not required here, since this is an *external* redirection, which *always* terminates the rewriting process for obvious reasons. For internal rewritings you should consider using the `end` flag instead of the old `L`.

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).